# Can't get gradient transparent border to display correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I am having trouble getting my Form background image to display correctly with a gradient transparency.  That is, the edge of the image (or anywhere for that matter) has a fading or non-255 Alpha value.  The result is that everywhere the Alpha is NOT 255 (or 0 - I can't remember) I see my background color.  Here is a [screen shot](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_XqB3s-LIbd0/TNzBgU-nj9I/AAAAAAAACZ4/Q9VStcDLz_g/keyMask%20FAIL.png):

What I have in this setup is a 24bit bmp file with a green background that I'm trying to key out via the Form.TransparencyKey property:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    Color key = ((Bitmap)this.BackgroundImage).GetPixel(0, 0);
    this.TransparencyKey = key;
}
```

I have also tried setting the Form's BackColor property to the same key value but that did not make a difference.

I also tried saving my image as a png with transparency and keying out the entire form background but that didn't work either.

I know this is possible somehow, I've seen applications like Photoshop use this for a decade.  I'm on WinXP Pro if that matters.

Anyone have experience with this and have an idea what step I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinForms implementation of `Form` only permits a solid colour to be used as the transparency key. It's not possible to have varying levels of transparency.

Most apps with splash screens like yours take a screenshot of the desktop (within the bounds that their splash screen *will* occupy) and then composite their splash screen on top of this screenshot. They then display the resulting bitmap to the user, giving the impression of an alpha gradient.

Comment: That's a clever solution to the problem.  If I can't pull off an acceptable look with a drop shadow I think I will go the screen shot route.  I've need screen cap functionality anyway so I might as well get in there and learn about it.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I've had my share of failure time with exactly that.
I found that WinForms is simple weak at handling this.
Here is some solutions that you might find useful:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112131608/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mswanson/archive/2005/07/07/436618.aspx)
http://www.vcskicks.com/splash-screen.php

Comment: one of those articles gave me the idea that I can probably just use a drop shadow to fake the effect that I'm after.  Thanks.